# Запрет на запуск дубликата приложения

Tags: android-sdk, java

Здравствуйте! Сижу думаю: Eclipse - Android. Тестирую приложение, все нормально, нажимаю кнопку `HOME` - приложение исчезает, но работает. Нажимаю на значок приложения - запускается дубликат - новое приложение.

Вопрос: как запретить повторный запуск, а вместо него восстановить уже запущенное приложение?

Comment: При старте проверяйте, создан ли именованный объект ядра, если создан - в завершение, если нет - создать его.

Comment: Спасибо! А пример можно выложить?
Или, может, ссылка есть на пример?

Answer (score 1):

Android на своем высшем от аппаратного обеспечения уровне никогда не запускает дубликатов! Вам следовало бы получше разобраться в жизненном цикле активностей( Activity ), чтобы мне не переписывать сюда строчки из мануала.

Android старается сохранять в кэше даже уже уничтоженные активности, чтобы в будущем было легче и менее ресурсозатратнее производить их запуск.
Когда же вы нажимаете на кнопку HOME, то приложение, если привести аналог, сворачивается, затормаживая свой жизненный цикл. За это отвечает менеджер активностей Android.

Для того, чтобы восстанавливать состояние приложения после его полного удаления из оперативной памяти, вам необходимо это состояние просто куда-нибудь сохранять. Об этом тоже следует почитать вам, а не пересказывать мне. К примеру, можете это делать, используя все вытекающее из `Activity.getPreferences()`